# Change NSManagedObject property without triggering delegate methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Is there any way (or tricks) where I can modify an `NSManagedObject` currently held by a delegated `NSFetchedResultsController` without triggering the `didChangeObject:` and `controllerWillChangeContent:` delegate methods?

For example, current if I change `myObject.property = @"hello";`, the delegate methods are triggered and updates are made to my table view, but I don't want that to happen, but only for certain changes where I explicitly specify, not all changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` method from `NSManagedObject` does exactly this, e.g.

```
[myObject setPrimitiveValue:@"hello" forKey:@"property"]
```

or, using the dynamically generated accessor methods:

```
[myObject setPrimitiveProperty:@"hello"]
```

But you should read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/setPrimitiveValue%3aforKey%3a) of that method, because there are some "Special Considerations".

A different approach could be to create a ["nested managed object context"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-SW1) and do all the modifications on that child context. Only when the child context is saved, the changes are propagated to the parent context.

Comment: What about if I wanted to have certain properties that don't trigger change notifications? Say that every time I modified the property "age", it wouldn't trigger change notifications. (Without me manually using setPrimitiveValue)

Comment: You could implement your own setAge: method that calls setPrimitiveAge: directly, but I doubt that that is a good idea because it will probably have unwanted side effects. Perhaps you can modify the fetch request of your FRC so that is does not depend on the "age" property?

Comment: Ya my FRC doesn't depend on the age property, but any time I change the object, it still calls the delegate methods with an update change..