# Make changes to NSManagedObject without triggering fetch controller delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I want to  make changes to an `NSManagedObject`, but without firing the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods. However, I do want to still have the changes propagate to the contexts, so that if I fetch based on these changes, the results do show up. I've tried the recommendation made in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11656240/458960), however the problem with this is that if I fetch based on these changes, I get no results, so not only are the delegate methods not firing (the desired result), but the context isn't made aware of these changes (an undesired result).

My goal is to strictly prevent ONLY the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods from firing when changes to certain properties are made, but I still want all other functionality to remain, such as KVO and whatever Core Data does behind the scenes to make sure contexts are made aware of the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSFetchedReresultsController will listen to notifications from the related entity on the related context. What you need to do is introduce some logic inside your delegate methods where you discard any update to the UI (if any) if the context did some changes to an object that you would like to ignore. If you are using the NSFetchedResultsController instance in full persistent tracking mode,the delegate methods will be called. It's the main purpose of NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you would want to that but, one way you could do it would be to o set some kind of global flag which would dictate proceeding with the UI update.

You would set a flag before saving the context and in your fetched results controller delegate method you would just check for that flag and if it's set you unset it and return to stop the UI.